# Is there a way I can cancel a running timer in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this timer in my code:

```
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100), () =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    if (detailGrid.IsVisible == true)
                    {
                        getRandomPhase();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Is there a way that I could (through a gesture) **cancel** the timer from running or abort the timer in some way?

Comment: You want stop the timer ? , return false is used to stop the timer only

Comment: use AdvancedTimer instead - https://github.com/ufuf/AdvancedTimer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of the Timer callback is a boolean that determines if the timer should keep running or stop. You can use a private variable to keep track if the timer should keep running and return it from the callback.

Please check this sample

```
private bool _isTimerStart = true;  

           private void StartTimers()  
           {  
               try  
               {  
                   Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>  
                   {  
                      // do some code here

                       return _isTimerStart;  
                   });  
               }  
               catch {}  
           }      private void BtnStart_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)  
           {  
               _isTimerStart = true;  
               StartTimers();  
           }  

           private void BtnStop_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)  
           {  
               _isTimerStart = false;  
           }
```

This code was taken from the following blog post which shows a more detailed example : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/quick-start-tutorial-creating-universal-apps-via-xamarin-device-classcont/

Comment: Please copy the relevant part of the solution to your post for reference and in case the link goes dead. You can still leave the url to credit the author.